# 2 VLANs, different subnets, NAT, EIGRP

Tags: nat, vlan, subnet, eigrp

I have following network:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPxus.jpg

So want to connect 2 subnets:

VLAN 10 - programmer - network `155.55.3.0 / 26` - left side

 VLAN 10 - programmer - network `155.55.0.0 / 23` - right side

 Hosts have address from DHCPs on each router
Routing method is EIGRP

I use NAT for VLAN translation

 Problem is that there is weird connection problem:

From **Router0** I can ping to **PC1**

From **PC0** i can ping max. to **Router1** (`10.0.0.2`)

From **Router1** I can ping max to **Router0** (`10.0.0.1`)

From **PC1** I can ping max to **Router0** (`10.0.0.1`)

Switch x2 - configuration:

> enable
> configure terminal
> vlan 10
> name programmer
> end
> interface range fastEthernet 0/1-17
> switchport access vlan 10
> exit
> interface range gigabitEthernet 0/1-2
> switchport mode trunk
> switchport trunk allowed vlan add 10
> end

Router0 configuration:

> enable 
>   configure terminal 
>   interface FastEthernet0/0.10 
>   encapsulation dot1Q 10 
>   ip address 155.55.3.1 255.255.255.192 
>   ip nat inside 
> no sh
> exit
>   interface FastEthernet1/0
>   ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
>   ip nat outside
>   no sh
>   exit
>   
>   router eigrp 10
>   network 155.55.3.0 255.255.255.192
>   network 155.55.0.0 255.255.254.0
>   network 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
>   no auto-summary
>   
>   access-list 101 permit ip any any
>   ip nat inside source list 101 interface FastEthernet1/0 overload
>   
>   ip dhcp pool programmer
>   network 155.55.3.0 255.255.255.192
>   default-router 155.55.3.1
>   ip dhcp excluded-address 155.55.3.1

Router 1 configuration:

> > enable 
> >     configure terminal 
> >     interface FastEthernet0/0.10 
> >     encapsulation dot1Q 10 
> >     ip address 155.55.0.1 255.255.254.0 
> >     ip nat inside 
> > no sh
> > exit
> >     interface FastEthernet1/0
> >     ip address 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0
> >     ip nat outside
> >     no sh
> >     exit
> >     
> >     router eigrp 10
> >     network 155.55.3.0 255.255.255.192
> >     network 155.55.0.0 255.255.254.0
> >     network 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
> >     no auto-summary
> >     
> >     access-list 101 permit ip any any
> >     ip nat inside source list 101 interface FastEthernet1/0 overload
> >     
> >     ip dhcp pool programmer
> >     network 155.55.0.0 255.255.254.0
> >     default-router 155.55.0.1
> >     ip dhcp excluded-address 155.55.0.1

Did I make some configuration mistakes? Is that even possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve problem. That was really unecessary to use here NAT transaltion.
I delete that and works perfectly :)